# Integrate Push Notification with UPS/FEDEX

Tags: push-notification, fedex, shipping-method, ups

We are trying to integrate the delivery status updates with FedEx and UPS.
ours is a retailer portal - like flipkart.
One way is to schedule a job(every four hours) to track all the TrackingIds and update them in a particular interval.

But the problem with this approach is we need to send all the trackingIds to Carrier even though there is no update. I heard there is another way - our application receives "push notification" from carrier whenever there is an update for a particular vendor tracking.

Does anyone tried this approach, it would be helpful if someone throw some light towards it.